# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrolly is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Консоль выводит такую проблему:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrolly is not a function
>
> at HTMLDocument. (main.js:133)
>
> at j (jquery.min.js:2)
>
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>
> at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
>
> at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)

Что это значит?
И кстати на локалке всё нормально работает

Comment: Показывает, что нету функции `scrolly` для элементов DOM

Comment: почему же на локалке всё нормально работает?

Comment: Я так понял это какой-то сторонний плагин вы подключаете. Уверены, что адрес верный?

Comment: да нет, всё в файлах https://vikapitoshka.github.io/jekyll-theme-future-imperfect/ вот

Comment: Порядок загрузки посмотрите: может у вас jQuery позже плагина загружается. Или `ready()` вы забыли использовать.

Comment: там не работает меню

Comment: и нет, jquery подключается самым первым

Comment: У вас некоторые скрипты не подгружаются (404 not found) проверьте наличие файлов и пути к ним

Comment: @Crantisz , в том то и дело, что не прогружается только menu.js , находящееся в папке assets: https://github.com/ViKapitoshka/testing/tree/master/assets/js